# How to close infowindow when clicking outside/map?

Tags: angularjs, ng-map

How to close infowindow when clicking map or outside of the map...

Ex:  `google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
infowindow.close();
});`

how to implement this code in ng-map?

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the solution my self for this..

```
$scope.$on("mapInitialized", function(evt, evtMap) {
    $scope.map = evtMap;           

    google.maps.event.addListener($scope.map, 'click', function(event) {
        $scope.map.hideInfoWindow('myInfoWindow', this);
    });
});
```